# Delete expired accounts in specific OUs

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

Trying to make a PS script that finds and deletes expired accounts in specific OUs

I've created this script, and it gets the users that is expired in the 4 OUs, so far so good, but I cant get my head around how to make it delete the users.

```
$OUs=
"OU=1,OU=Users,DC=Test,DC=local",
"OU=2,OU=Users,DC=Test,DC=local",
"OU=3,OU=Users,DC=Test,DC=local",
"OU=4,OU=Users,DC=Test,DC=local"

Foreach($OU in $OUs){
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired -Searchbase $OU | Select-Object Name
}
```

Anybody that got a solution for this? :)

Comment: Are you able to pipe it to Remove-ADObject and see if it's deleting objects? `Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired -Searchbase $OU | Select-Object Name | % {Remove-ADObject}`

Comment: @MuditBahedia 's answer is correct. If you know it's always user objects, you could also pipe it to `| Remove-ADUser -Confirm:False`

Comment: Thanks for you help, both of you. 
But neither is working, If I use @trebleCode suggestion it just gives me the error:
"Remove-ADUser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of
 the parameters that take pipeline input."

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine

```
Foreach($OU in $OUs){
    Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired -Searchbase $OU | Remove-ADObject -Confirm:$false
}
```